# How to define variables in .gitlab-ci.yml to ask for input variable during runtime

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, packer

How to define variables in .gitlab-ci.yml to ask for input variable during runtime

Comment: One comment here, the use of the `variables` clause in the last example isn't what you want, and as noted above it fails validation. `variables` is a dictionary/hash and should be `variable_name: value`. So, you'd want `- RELEASE: 'yes'`  With all that said, if you want to do 3 different versions of the same script with one variable different, you may want to try using [parallel:matrix](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/06/21/how-to-become-more-productive-with-gitlab-ci/)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the runtime of gitlab cicd is not interactive and thus you can not input variable during the pipeline execution. However, you can set a variable before executing a pipeline, if that helps. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxMo3.png)

[image: ENV variable before pipeline execution]